# Can I run different docker containers on different EC2 instances on Beanstalk Enviroment?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have different services on which my application depends on such as nginx, celery, flower, otel, etc. Within an Elastic Beanstalk can I run each service on different instance and connect them?

Edit:
Services are running on docker-compose on ec2 instances in a beanstalk environment I want to use one of those services (celery) out of the environment in a separate ec2 instance on the docker container but how will I manage to connect that service to the environment's containers.
In my existing workflow, I use docker-compose for this (specifically depends-on parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. To run multiple services on an Elastic Beanstalk instance, you only need to add container definitions to the Dockerrun.aws.json file that should be part of your application version.

AWS has good docs on how to do this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html#create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial_config

Comment: I have already done that but one of those services needs to be deployed separately out of the beanstalk environment in another ec2 instance but in a same vpc. Now how will I connect that docker container which is out side of Beanstalk environmental to the instances inside of the environment. in my existing workflow I use docker compose to connect different services using depends on the parameter.